# Search for object in array by parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I used created an array of objects belonging to a class. Each object has values that are unique to themselves. I need to find class a parameter's value belongs to.

For example

```
 class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


 dogNames = ["Rex", "Otis", "Max"]
 dogs = []
 for dog in dogNames:
    dogs.append(Dog(dog))


 >>> dogs
    [<__main__.Dog instance at 0x1181c5cf8>, <__main__.Dog instance at 0x117c7a050>, <__main__.Dog instance at 0x117d169e0>]
```

I would need to find which object has the name "Rex" assigned to it.

What is the most Pythonic way of doing this ?

Comment: `[d for d in dogs if d.name=="Rex"]`

Comment: or `next((d for d in dogs if d.name=="Rex"),None)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: You have to parenthesize the genexp if you want to pass a second argument to `next`.

Comment: @user2357112 right! obviously I didn't try it. Always get caught by that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the names are unique, don't create a list, create a dictionary:

```
 dog_names = ["Rex", "Otis", "Max"]
 dogs = {name:Dog(name) for name in dog_names}
```

now you can perform fast dict lookup with default value to `None` if name not found:

```
rex_object = dogs.get("Rex")
```

if you want to keep your list, the same thing can be achieved (but with `O(n)` complexity with a generator expression and `next` defaulting to `None` if no dog is called "Rex":

```
next((d for d in dogs if d.name=="Rex"),None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you happen to know the complexity of the dictionary approach ? I'm hesitant to using a dictionary,  a) because of the speed, and b) because I need to keep the list in order

Comment: the complexity (average) is O(1). If you want to keep order, create an `collections.OrderedDict()` instead and insert items in a loop

Answer (score 1):

the most pythonicway is to use `repr` dunder method in your `Dog` class

```
class Dog:  
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'dog name is {}'.format(self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is through the existing for loop that you have and just throw in an if statement to check if the name equals the name you're looking for and assign it to a variable.

```
find = ""

for dog in dogNames:
    if dog.name == "Rex":
        find = dog
```

Comment: avoid changing the type of your variables mid-execution, especially conditionally